# Accessing Incoming WebHook JSON payload in Bash - Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I'm building an azure pipeline and using an Incoming WebHook as the trigger.

I need to access the data I'm sending in the JSON Payload in Bash, the documentation only has the following example in PowerShell and there no any other docs about how to access that Payload

```yaml
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: MyWebhookTrigger          ### Webhook alias
      connection: MyWebhookConnection    ### Incoming webhook service connection
      filters:
        - path: repositoryName      ### JSON path in the payload
          value: maven-releases     ### Expected value in the path provided
        - path: action
          value: CREATED
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
    script: |
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.repositoryName}}
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.component.group}}
```

I tried to check the Environment Variables in bash but couldn't find anything there any pointers on what this means `${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.repositoryName}}` in Powershell and how can I do the same in bash?

Comment: Any news on this? I have used Ngrok to see the payload of my webhook and can see all necessary information but when I try to access the content of the payload even with the Powershell script above I get empty strings?

Comment: @SebastianBalle it turns out that this `${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.repositoryName}}`  was just was the syntax for accessing a variable in YAML

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out as well. The variables, however, must be utilized in the script where the webhook resource is specified. It is not possible to source these variables are parameters in a template extension as I use them heavily.

Comment: @SebastianBalle can you please elaborate more in a separate answer maybe how do you consume the variables defined in the source (where the webhook is coming from) in the target pipeline with parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example using Bash to write the value of part of the webhook payload.

Please note the extra `pr: none` and `trigger: none` in the example. This prevents the pipeline from being executed with non-webhook triggers that will result in an empty webhook payload... because it wasn't triggered by a webhook. [Azure DevOps Pipeline Incoming Webhook from GitHub: Json Payload empty in pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670429/azure-devops-pipeline-incoming-webhook-from-github-json-payload-empty-in-pipeli)

```yaml
# file: azure-pipeline.yml

# These lines prevent default non-webhook events from executing the pipeline
pr: none
trigger: none

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: BasicWebhook          ### Webhook alias
      connection: BasicWebhookConnection    ### Incoming webhook service connection


steps:
- script: |
    echo ${{parameters.BasicWebhook.repository}}
```