# Azure DevOps Pipeline Incoming Webhook from GitHub: Json Payload empty in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

#### Introduction

Hi there, I'm trying to create a webhook from GitHub to trigger an Azure DevOps (ADO) Pipeline with parameters from the webhook request body. The ADO pipeline, however, doesn't seem to be aware of any of info from the request body.

I've set up an Azure DevOps incoming webhook following their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#define-a-webhooks-resource

#### GitHub Outgoing Webhook is Successful

From GitHub, I've set up the outcoming webhook and the deliveries are successful to Azure DevOps. Note some of info in the payload:
[image: Screenshot of webhook delivery from GitHub]

#### Azure DevOps Yaml Pipeline: Incoming Webhook Resource

On the Azure DevOps side, however, it doesn't seem to receive info from the JSON body, however. Here's my simple pipeline, following the documentation's example:

```yaml
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: CleanUpPREnv          ### Webhook alias
      connection: CleanUpPREnvWebhookConnection    ### Incoming webhook service connection

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
    script: |
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.CleanUpPREnv.before}}
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.CleanUpPREnv.repository.full_name}}
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.CleanUpPREnv.repository}}
```

#### Azure DevOps Pipeline doesn't have payload data

The pipeline run writes empty strings on lines 12-14, however:
[image]

#### Works with Postman; Other Thoughts

Interestingly, I can get this to work using a Postman request, so I know the fundamentals are working. There's just something I'm missing between GitHub and Azure DevOps that I can't figure out. Any insights would be appreciated... otherwise maybe we do need to migrate to GitHub Actions from Azure DevOps pipelines, lol.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm on to something. When I made changes in GitHub and it would fire off an outgoing webhook to Azure DevOps, my pipeline would also be triggered by default for a CI activity.

When the pipeline is triggered based on CI activity, not an incoming webhook, it doesn't have any of the info from the webhook obviously. This might be it!

Answer (score 3):

The Azure DevOps (ADO) pipeline that was supposed to be triggered by an incoming webhook was also being triggered by default CI and PR triggers. When the pipeline is run by one of those triggers, it obviously lacks the data expected from the JSON webhook payload (because a webhook didn't trigger that run of the pipeline!).

Adding the following code the pipeline to disable CI and PR triggers prevents this behavior, such that the pipeline ONLY runs when the webhook is triggered and includes desired webhook request data:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none
```

A full example of an Azure DevOps Yaml Pipeline that is only triggered from an incoming webhook would look like this:

```yaml
# file: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: MyWebhookTrigger          
      connection: MyWebhookConnection    

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.repositoryName}} ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.MyWebhookTrigger.component.group}}
```

By disabling non-webhook triggers, you can ensure it only runs from an incoming webhook and includes the expected data from the webhook's request body.

Comment: Hi! By some chance have you managed to make this work using a secret? I have been able to accomplish the same that you showed here but when adding secrets I am having a lot of issues: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8913

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with similar symptoms but a different cause.

It turns out that one must use `${{}}`, not `${}` to access `paramaters`, because `parameters` is a YAML variable, not a PowerShell variable.

(Credit to [Accessing Incoming WebHook JSON payload in Bash - Azure Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255374/accessing-incoming-webhook-json-payload-in-bash-azure-pipelines#comment121904175_68255374) for this )